# OneHotEncoder confusion in scikit learn

Tags: python, python-2.7, machine-learning, scikit-learn, one-hot-encoding

Using in Python 2.7 (miniconda interpreter). Confused by the example below about `OneHotEncoder`, confused why `enc.n_values_` output is `[2, 3, 4]`? If anyone could help to clarify, it will be great.

http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder.html

```
>>> from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder
>>> enc = OneHotEncoder()
>>> enc.fit([[0, 0, 3], [1, 1, 0], [0, 2, 1], [1, 0, 2]])  
OneHotEncoder(categorical_features='all', dtype=<... 'float'>,
       handle_unknown='error', n_values='auto', sparse=True)
>>> enc.n_values_
array([2, 3, 4])
>>> enc.feature_indices_
array([0, 2, 5, 9])
>>> enc.transform([[0, 1, 1]]).toarray()
array([[ 1.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.]])
```

regards,
Lin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`n_values` is the number of values per feature.

In this example,

```
X = 0 0 3
    1 1 0
    0 2 1
    1 0 2
```

(X's shape is [n_samples, n_feature])

For the first feature, there are 2 values: 0, 1;

For the second feature, there are 3 values: 0, 1, 2.

For the third feature, there are 4 values: 0, 1, 2, 3.

Therefore, `enc.n_values_` is `[2, 3, 4]`.

Comment: Thanks yangjie, so the 3 samples are `[0, 1, 0, 1]`, `[0, 1, 2, 0]` and `[3, 0, 1, 2]`?

Comment: Also confused about ` [n_samples, n_feature]`, I thought it is `n_samples` rows and `n_feature` columns, but it seems not the case, if you could clarity, it will be great. :)

Comment: It is `n_samples` rows and `n_feature` columns. There are 4 samples in X, each sample has 3 features.

Comment: Got it, thanks yangjie, your description is much clearer than scikit learn document. :)

Comment: Mark your reply as answer to benefit others. :)

Answer (score 0):

I think that the above explanation about n_values_ is not complete and clear.My explanation :-
With this : "n_values[i] is the number of categorical values in
X[:, i]. Each feature value should be in range(n_values[i])  " 
this meant that the n_values_ gives the range(n_values[i]) = [0,n_values) in column.

here :

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder
o = OneHotEncoder()
o.fit([[1,2,3], [1,2,3], [1,2,11] , [2,3,1]])
o.n_values_
array([3,4,12])
```

Here the result is 3,4,12 so you can see it more clearly by colum each value in array gives the range.

```
1 2 3
1 2 3
1 2 11
2 3 1
```

So column wise values are range(3) , range(4), range(12). To understand more clearly lets take one more example : -

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder
o = OneHotEncoder()
o.fit([[1,2,3,100], [1,2,3,200], [1,2,11,300] , [2,3,1,400]])
o.n_values_
array([ 3, 4, 12, 401])
```

this proved that it looks column wise for the categorical data and each feature values lies in range(n_values_)